# Interceptor in @WebServlet not activated

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi, jboss-weld

We have a @WebServlet that's annotated with a custom interceptor annotation like this:

```
@WebServlet("/path")
@CustomInterceptor
public class InitialHtmlServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
  }
}
```

We have the CustomInterceptor in the beans.xml in /WEB-INF and the interceptor works in other CDI-components. In this servlet, however, we cannot get it working.

We're running the latest JBoss EAP, which should be somewhat similar to JBoss 7.1.1. Is there something we should do different to get the interceptor to catch invocations on the servlet or is this not possible at all?

Comment: Are you sure you can intercept calls to _servlets_?

Comment: No, that's part of the question as stated in: " Is there something we should do different to get the interceptor to catch invocations on the servlet or is this not possible at all?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around I also found it somewhat confusing, that while being a good candidate for calling it a 'bean', servlet are exempt from interceptor mechanism.

It looks like various parts of JEE6 may or may not support interceptors at will :). Found some discussion [here](http://java.net/projects/servlet-spec/lists/jsr340-experts/archive/2012-02/message/0).

Comment: Thanks for the good reference. Got a similar answer by e-mail from RedHat JBoss support. Still think it's confusing though. The specs could be clearer on this point...